# Как делать выражения, которые образуют число? Javascript

Tags: javascript

Если вставить код внизу в консоль браузера, то она, в ответ, даст число 69.
`(!![]+!![])*(+([]!=[])+([]!=[]))*(([[]]!=[[]])+([[]]!=[[]]))*(([[[]]]!=[[]])+([[]]!=[[[]]]))*(([[[[]]]]!=[[]])+([[]]!=[[[[]]]]))*(([[[[]]]]!=[[]])+([[]]!=[[[[]]]]))+(([[[[]]]]!=[[[]]])+([[[]]]!=[[[[]]]]))*(([[[!![]]]]!=[[[]]])+([[[]]]!=[[[!![]]]]))+!![]`

Как делать такие выражения? Например, число 81 образовалось в выражение

Comment: Вот будет 81 `(([]!={})+!![]+!!{})**(([]!={})+!![]+!!{}+!![])`

Comment: Состаляете математическое выражение создающее нужное число из 1 с помощью сложений и умножений. Меняете в выражении каждую 1 на что угодно, дающее true. например `!![]` при сложении равноценно единице, так же как и `[]!=[]` и даже `[[[]]]!=[[[[]]]]` то же всего лишь обычная единица

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, что-нибудь в этом духе, причем тут можно много чего еще добавить, но уже лень. :)

```js
function factorize(num) {
  num |= 0; // to integer
  let factors = [];
  let isPrime = false;
  while (!isPrime) {
    isPrime = true;
    for (let i = 2; i * i <= num; i++ ) {
      if (!(num % i)) {
        num /= i;
        factors.push(i);
        isPrime = false;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  factors.push(num);
  return factors;
}

function obfuscatePrime(num) {
  let res = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    res.push(get1());
  }
  return res.join('+');
  function get1() {
    const ones = ['!![]', '!!([]!=[])', '(+!([]==[]))'];
    let res = ones[(Math.random() * 3) | 0];
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) // больше скобок!
      res = res.replace(/\[\]/g, () => Math.random() > 0.5 ? '[]' : '[[]]')
    return res;
  }
}

function obfuscate(num) {
  return `(${factorize(num).map(obfuscatePrime).join(')*(')})`;
}

console.log(`69 = ${obfuscate(69)}`);
console.log(`81 = ${obfuscate(81)}`);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!